# Отложенные задачи в AWS

Tags: очередь, amazon-web-services

Как лучше реализовать выполнение отложенных задач в AWS? Задача может быть отложена на час или большее время, поэтому SQS не подходит.

Спасибо.

Comment: я не спец в aws, но как вариант: я бы положил такие задачи в dynamodb, накатал бы лямбду и CloudWatch эвент, который бы каждый час триггерил лямбду. Лямбда бы собирала все отсроченные задачи и запускала бы их сама или кадала бы в SQS другим лямбдам на обработку.

Comment: Ну да... Видимо других вариантов нет...

Comment: Есть еще step functions, но я с этим не работал https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html